# OpenCV4Android Kalman filter Assertion Failed at matmul

Tags: android, opencv, java-native-interface, sigabrt, kalman-filter

I have a problem with OpenCV4Android. I'm using it's newest version 2.4.10 although it seems, that the issue also occurs in 2.4.9.
Whenever I'm trying to implement 2d kalman filter with JNI on Android, the code is failing, because of errors like this (then the method throws me SIGABRT and there is nothing I can do):

```
OpenCV Error: Assertion failed (type == B.type() && (type == CV_32FC1 ||
type == CV_64FC1 || type == CV_32FC2 || type == CV_64FC2)) in void
cv::gemm(cv::InputArray, cv::InputArray, double, cv::InputArray, double,
cv::OutputArray, int), file
/hdd2/buildbot/slaves/slave_ardbeg1/50-SDK/opencv/modules/core/src/matmul.cpp, line 711
```

It seems, that kalmanFilter.predict() method throws it.

I tried two other implementations- one taken directly from internet, second slightly different.

I remember, that (in order to use it properly) I must first predict the point, then correct the filter, that isn't the issue.
My assumption is that, there is something weird at the junction of weird android world and c++ (maybe the float values aren't 32bit floats in android's JNI? I'm unable to tell..)

Here is my code:

```
class Kalman{
private:
    KalmanFilter kalmanFilter;
    Mat_<float> measurement;
    bool inited;
public:
    void init(float startX, float startY){
        inited = true;
        kalmanFilter = KalmanFilter(4, 2, 0);
        float tmpArr[4][4] = {{1,0,1,0}, {0,1,0,1}, {0,0,1,0}, {0,0,0,1}};
        kalmanFilter.transitionMatrix = Mat(4,4,CV_32FC1, &tmpArr);
        measurement = Mat(2,1,CV_32FC1);
        measurement.setTo(Scalar(0));
        kalmanFilter.statePre.at<float>(0) = startX;
        kalmanFilter.statePre.at<float>(1) = startY;
        kalmanFilter.statePre.at<float>(2) = 0;
        kalmanFilter.statePre.at<float>(3) = 0;
        setIdentity(kalmanFilter.measurementMatrix);
        setIdentity(kalmanFilter.processNoiseCov, Scalar::all(1e-4));
        setIdentity(kalmanFilter.measurementNoiseCov, Scalar::all(10));
        setIdentity(kalmanFilter.errorCovPost, Scalar::all(.1));
    }
    Kalman(){}
    Kalman(float startX, float startY){
        this->init(startX, startY);
    }
    Geometry::Point newPrediction(){
        Geometry::Point res;
        if(inited){
            Log::d("Kalman", "newPrediction pre!");
            Mat prediction = kalmanFilter.predict();
            Log::d("Kalman", "newPrediction post!");
            res.x = prediction.at<float>(0);
            res.y = prediction.at<float>(1);
        }
        return res;
    }
    void correction(float x, float y){
        measurement(0) = x;
        measurement(1) = y;
        Log::d("Kalman", "correction pre!");
        kalmanFilter.correct(measurement);
        Log::d("Kalman", "correction post!");
    }

};
```

Community, please help me!

Comment: probably not the reason, but imho your transition matrix is invalid (borrowed pointer) after leaving init(); you should clone it: `kalmanFilter.transitionMatrix = Mat(4,4,CV_32FC1, &tmpArr).clone();`

Comment: I'm checking it now.  

   **edit**     

It didn't help. But thanks for advice. I didn't know this ;)

Comment: changes : `kalmanFilter = KalmanFilter(4, 2, 0, CV_64F);

(...)

kalmanFilter.transitionMatrix = Mat(4,4,CV_64FC1,&tmpArr).clone();

measurement = Mat(2,1,CV_64FC1);`
didn't helped.